# Tune indices when update multiple fields on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, index

On a PostgreSQL 14.5 database, there is the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Points"
(
    "Key" character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "ReferencedKeys" text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "State" integer NOT NULL,
    "OtherKey" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Points" PRIMARY KEY ("Key")
)

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IX_Points_OtherKey"
    ON public."Points" USING btree
    ("OtherKey" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IX_Points_ReferencedKeys"
    ON public."Points" USING gin
    ("ReferencedKeys" COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IX_Points_State"
    ON public."Points" USING btree
    ("State" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

The table contains roughly 2e7 records with the following distribution of `State`:

| State | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1900000 |
| 4 | 200 |

There are 4100 different `OtherKey`s.

Now the relevant statement which takes about 10 s:

```sql
UPDATE "Points" AS i
SET "State" = 0
WHERE i."OtherKey" = 'MyKeyId' AND i."State" NOT IN (0, 4, 3);
```

`EXPLAIN` in pgAdmin shows this:
[image]
The blurred *Key* conditions refer to `OtherKey`.

From my gut feeling, I'd have thought that PostgreSQL would choose the index `IX_Points_OtherKey` as it's more selective, which doesn't seem to be the case.

So I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain why PostgreSQL prefers the index `IX_Points_State` and how I could improve this query.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no PostgreSQL expert, but it seems to me that PostgreSQL is indeed using `IX_Points_OtherKey` with a Bitmax Index Scan, searching the index for `"OtherKey" = 'MyKeyId'`.

Then it will check the selected rows to check if they satisfy the `State` filter and finally it will update those rows which satisfy both conditions.

Explain output has to be read from the inner most operations to the outer.

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OwjhE0iT)

Comment: Thank you for that explanation - I read it like a stack